# Why do i get error on prepare?

Tags: perl

```js
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Sybase::DBlib;

use Sys::Hostname;
use Getopt::Std;

## additionals
use lib "/opt/chsdjg/perllib";
use ADDITIONALS;

  my ($dsn, $database, $dbserver, $dbname, $user, $passwd, $rmdb_config ) = ('','','','','','','');

  my $dbhandle;
  $rmdb_config  = "$ENV{ENV_DIR}";
  $dsn          = "dbi:Sybase";
  $database     = join (' ~ ',$dsn, $dbserver, $dbname, $user, $passwd, $rmdb_config);
  $dbhandle     = connect_me($database);

  my $ctl= "select * from table_name";
 
  $dbhandle->dbcmd($ctl);
  my $ret = $dbhandle->dbsqlexec;
  my $res = $dbhandle->dbresults;

  
 my @dat;
   while($dbhandle->dbresults != NO_MORE_RESULTS) {
        while(@dat = $dbhandle->dbnextrow) {
  print "@dat\n";
}
}
```

I didnt use the right connection the first time. This is the code now, it makes an select statement and shows the result. Hope it helps people.

Comment: So you don't have `use strict` in your original script. Why did you add it to the code above?

Comment: In line 5 you set `$dbhandle` and later use `$dbh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never create your database handle ($dbh is undefined).

Add

```
my $dbh = $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
            or die $DBI::errstr;
```

To your code. See [Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm#connect) on CPAN for more information.